# Getting notification of sales/refunds done through Square POS/Connect

Tags: webhooks, square-connect

I would like to integrate my web application with the [Square](http://squareup.com) POS.

The goal would be to be notified each time a transaction (sale/refund/etc) is processed by Square for an account so that I can update inventory levels etc, ultimately so I can update inventory levels as transactions occur.

From what I can tell, it seems that the Square API's seem to be designed around my application initiating the transaction, then handing off to Square to process the payment. I simply want to be notified that a transaction has happened so that I can update inventory.

Is it possible to do this? Or is the Square API just for processing payments?

edit: After some more reading, I still haven't found a webhook to be notified, but it looks like I can ListTransactions, and RetrieveTransaction, so if I poll I should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re correct. Square’s API Webhooks will be what you’ll use to be notified each time a transaction is created or updated. We have a quick setup guide available in Square’s Developer Doc (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/?q=webhooks#setupwebhooks).

The PAYMENT_UPDATED webhook will alert you every time a payment is made, so that you can update your inventory.

Comment: Perfect. I must have not come accross it assuming that the v2 API replaced the V1. But it seems V2 adds to the V1 api?

Comment: Exactly! V2 adds to the V1 API.

Comment: "V2 adds to V1" makes sense but is not stated clearly on the V2 docs and thus I have wasted quite some time!

Comment: @Kaled is this answer still accurate? Your link is dead and the Webhooks page does not mention a PAYMENT_UPDATED Webhook.

Comment: Hey @ChristianCuevas Yes, it's still the only why to be notified that a payment has been updated. Here is the link to our Webhooks overview: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/webhooks-overview Additionally, you might look into our v2 webhooks which includes a more robust Inventory webhook. https://developer.squareup.com/docs/webhooks-api/what-it-does